# sending value url from ipcRender to ipcMain

Tags: electron

Hey i am making a project where i want to send data to ipc main

my index.js

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow , ipcMain} = require('electron')
const ejse = require('ejs-electron')

app.on('ready', () => {
    ipcMain.on("getUrl",(event,url)=>{
        console.log(url);
    })

    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        autoHideMenuBar: true,
        icon: __dirname + '/logo.ico',
        webPreferences: {
            devTools: false,
            nodeIntegration:true,
            webviewTag:true
        }
    })

    mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/files/index.ejs');
})
```

index.ejs contains a anchor tag with value as link

```html
<button id="dw" style="display: none;"><a class="button" id="dwl" onclick="heal()" value="#">Download</a></button>
<script src=download.js></script>
```

download.js i am able to alert the link but ipcRender not working

```js
const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

function heal(){
    var url = document.getElementById("dwl").value;
    alert(url);
    ipcRenderer.send("getUrl",url);
}
```

i am not able to send url from ejs file to main index.js file alert is working in download.js but some error in sending data to main file console.log is not working

Comment: i have added
```<button id="dw" style="display: none;"><a class="button" id="dwl" onclick="heal()" value="github.com/healer-op">Download</a></button>

Answer (score 0):

The use of `contextBridge` within your `preload.js` script safely exposes API's you approve for use in your render
scripts.

Whist understanding how all this works can be challenging at first, becoming familiar with the below content and the
following code should put you in good stead for a solid understanding of how you can wire up your application.

- [Context Isolation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation)

  - [contextBridge](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge)

    - [Enabling Content Isolation for remote content](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#3-enable-context-isolation-for-remote-content)
- [Inter-Process Communication](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc)

  - [ipcMain](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main)
  - [ipcRenderer](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer)
  - [webContents - contents.send(channel, ...args)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-args)

> Some people like to implement concrete functions within their `preload.js` script(s). In this example,
> the `preload.js` script is only used to configure whitelisted channel names for use between the main process and render
> process(es). This keeps your code seperated. IE: Separation of concerns.

---

Let's set the channel name `getUrl` within the `ipc.render.send` array.

`preload.js` (main process)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron components.
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels.
const ipc = {
    'render': {
        // From render to main.
        'send': [
            'getUrl' // Channel name
        ],
        // From main to render.
        'receive': [],
        // From render to main and back again.
        'sendReceive': []
    }
};

// Exposed protected methods in the render process.
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods.
    'ipcRender', {
        // From render to main.
        send: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        // From main to render.
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.receive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`.
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From render to main and back again.
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.sendReceive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

---

Let's set the `webPreferences.contextIsolation` value to `true` and specify the `webPreferences.preload` path.

> `webPreferences.nodeIntegration` can be set to `false`, but in doing so `webPreferences.contextIsolation` should be
> set to `true` to "truly enforce strong isolation and prevent the use of Node primitives".

Lastly, let's listen for a message from the render process on the `getUrl` channel.

`main.js` (main process)

```js
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

const nodePath = require("path");

// Prevent garbage collection
let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// Listen for a message on the 'getUrl' channel
electronIpcMain.on('getUrl', (event, url) => {
    console.log(url);
})
```

---

This file is fairly standard and easy to understand. Just adapt code for use with `.ejs`

> Added Javascript code in between `<script>` tags for sake of brevity.

`index.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" id="dwl" value="#">
    </body>

    <script>
        let button = document.getElementById('dwl');

        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            // Send URL on the 'getUrl' channel
            window.ipcRender.send('getUrl', button.value);
        });
    </script>
</html>
```